# asp.net Core mvc hide and exclude Web Api Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know there is the *ApiExplorerSettings* attribute

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(int id)
```

But that does not stop a client of the api to call the endpoint method.

I need to know if there is an attribute that disables the endpoint and does not allow requests. I want to avoid doing it by modifying the routing mechanism.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The simplest MVC approach might be to use the [`NonAction`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/NonActionAttribute.cs) attribute, like so:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[NonAction]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(int id)
```

Another option is to just change the method's access modifier from `public` to e.g. `private` for the same effect.

If you'd like to exclude an entire *controller*, there's the [`NonController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.noncontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attribute:

```
[NonController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: Is it possible to set IgnoreApi to true for all controllers?  I have more controller that I need to hide right now.

Comment: @HungryWolf [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-apiexplorer-to-document-an-app) might be helpful.

Comment: Used this today to replace the parameter used in an overriden controller method by setting the override to NonAction the aspcore router happily routes to the new method without an ambiguity