# Error: Action has more than one parameter bound from request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wrote a new method into my Controller of my ASP.Net MVC project and getting error below. I think `InvalidOperationException` coming from with Swagger. I marked it as "ignored Api" hoping it will skip the method but error still there:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public decimal CalculatePriceWithCampaign(
       BeverageCapacityCampaign campaign, 
       BeverageCapacity capacity,
       int count = 1)
{
    switch (campaign.DiscountType)
    {
        case DiscountType.Fixed:
            return (capacity.CapacityPrice - campaign.DiscountValue) * count;
        case DiscountType.Percentage:
            return (capacity.CapacityPrice * count) * campaign.DiscountValue;
        default:
            return capacity.CapacityPrice;
    }
}
```

But when running I am getting this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Action 'Gorilla.WebApi.Source.Controller.Campaigns.BeverageCapacityCampaignController.CalculatePriceWithCampaign (Gorilla.WebApi)' has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body. Inspect the following parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to specify bound from query, 'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from route, and 'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body:
>
>     BeverageCapacityCampaign campaign
>
>     BeverageCapacity capacity

Information I could find suggested to check nugets, but all my Nugets are up-to-date.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The error is coming from model binding and is not related to Swagger (the presence of `ApiExplorerSettings` attribute has no impact on error).

You have two complex parameters. i.e. of Complex types

```
BeverageCapacityCampaign 
BeverageCapacity
```

The **default** for **Model Binding** is to **bind complex parameters from the body** of the request. However, **only one parameter per action may be bound from body**.

So you need to either

1. Combine them into one class that just wraps / holds both parameters
   as properties - and have them bound from the body (as one object)
2. Decide which to bind from the body, and which from
   the route or the query and add the attributes [FromRoute] or [FromQuery] to one, and [FromBody] to the other.

`ApiExplorerSettings` from `System.Web.Http.Description` will ignore the attributed action from a help page, or whatever else (maybe swagger)... but you will still get this exception - from problems at level of Model Binding

Answer (score 14):

My controller has some refactored code whose methods are marked public.  Looks like either moving them out of the controller or marking private corrects this problem.  Or attributing the pesky methods with `[NonAction]` might also be a choice as asked at [asp.net Core mvc hide and exclude Web Api Controller Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328654/asp-net-core-mvc-hide-and-exclude-web-api-controller-method)

Comment: In my case i marked as protected, because it is an abstract method.

Comment: Thanks!!!  I was going to puke if I didn't find a solution!

Answer (score 11):

For me in the definition of the a new controller automatically add this prerequisite.
I removed it and it works

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Apicontroller] //remove this line
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem but solved it by declaring my method as private.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33219670)

Comment: @Oliver, take a look at the answer from No Refunds No Returns above. It's practically the same, so go ahead and leave your very useful comment in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I received error "has more than one parameter that was specified ..." for having mention of [ApiController] on top of class and then inheriting class from APIController.

Corrected issue by inheriting the class from Controller.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/the")]
**[ApiController]**
public class TheController : **Controller**
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by inheriting from BaseController instead of ControllerBase. It was a class from another library that is completely unrelated and I misremembered the name. The exception was a red herring for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that in the controller I had public methods that are not endpoints. And the ASP.NET Core mapping for controllers treats all public methods as endpoints and tries to map the request model because it uses reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using the ABP Framework. The reason was that my Controller method (POST) was taking 2 complex objects (i.e. `DispatchmentDto dispatchmentDto` and `FicheDto ficheDto`).

To fix this, I replaced my existing Controller method input:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("get-or-create-dispatchment-fiche")]
public Task<DispatchmentFicheDto> GetOrCreateDispatchmentFiche(DispatchmentDto dispatchmentDto, FicheDto ficheDto)
{
    return _aracFaturasAppService.GetOrCreateDispatchmentFiche(dispatchmentDto, ficheDto);
}
```

With a new consolidated class input:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("get-or-create-dispatchment-fiche")]
public Task<DispatchmentFicheDto> GetOrCreateDispatchmentFiche(DispatchmentFicheDto input)
{
    return _aracFaturasAppService.GetOrCreateDispatchmentFiche(input);
}
```

My consolidated `DispatchmentFicheDto` class is:

```cs
public class DispatchmentFicheDto
{
    public DispatchmentDto DispatchmentDto {get;set;}
    public FicheDto FicheDto {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem when I added an endpoint to a previously functional API that contained multiple fields that were pulled from the body of a POST request. I tried out several of the suggestions on this page and I found that several are correct, but approach the problem from differing sides.

[image: My test code]

By playing around with the suggestions made by Jesus Nieves and MemeDeveloper, I discovered that (in my case) the error was caused by using the [FromBody] decoration on multiple API input parameters. One works just fine, but two or more blows up.

One fix that seems to work was removing the class decoration of [ApiController] from the controller. I have no proof for why this works, but I suspect that since my class was named Controller, and inherits from ControllerBase that   the compiler is able to infer the class is a controller w/o the extra decoration, and adding it is introducing an extra layer that is getting tripped up when trying to unpack the POST body.

So, you probably can refactor to use a POCO that maps directly to the payload body and just use a single parameter OR you can try to ditch the apparently unneeded class decoration to mark your controller(s). I tried renaming the class and file, and it still works fine, so I am sticking with the theory that anything that inherits from ControllerBase will fly.

I am going to go with removing the [ApiController] decoration, because less is more.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is to nest the complex data types in a tuple:

```cs
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public decimal CalculatePriceWithCampaign((BeverageCapacityCampaign campaign, BeverageCapacity capacity) data, int count = 1)
{
    switch (data.campaign.DiscountType)
    {
        case DiscountType.Fixed:
            return (data.capacity.CapacityPrice - data.campaign.DiscountValue) * count;
        case DiscountType.Percentage:
            return (data.capacity.CapacityPrice * count) * data.campaign.DiscountValue;
        default:
            return data.capacity.CapacityPrice;
    }
}
```

However, NSwag (Swagger) does not seems to be able to automatically parse this case because a non-valid example gets generated. NSwagStudio recognizes the case correctly and generates valid client code.