# Change default source for custom `IModelBinder`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a strongly typed id to prevent ids from entity A from being mixed with entity B, like so:

```cs
public record struct Id<TEntity>(int Value);
```

I also created and registered an `IModelBinder` and a `IModelBinderProvider`, so that I can have the following signature in my controller:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetById(Id<Product> id);
```

This has one problem however. While `int` parameters have the `[FromRoute]` binding source by default, my `Id` struct defaults to the `[FromBody]` binding source, requiring me to explicitly add the attribute:

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetById([FromRoute] Id<Product> id);
```

So my question is, how can I change the default binding source from the binder/provider, without using annotations (including on `Id`)?

Comment: I'm not sure which ModelBinderProvider [FromRoute] uses, but I would think you could insert it in the first postion: `builder.Services.AddControllers(o => o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, x));`  x being the provider that `[FromRoute]` uses. Sorry not much help.

Comment: Are you working with a webapi project? if so just remove [ApiController] attribute

Comment: What's the purpose of `Id<Product>` ? It seems you're leaking the *implementation details* of a custom "repository" into your API model. That's the cause of this problem, not the model binder. Your API Model isn't the same as your business model or your database model. Sometimes they are close or even the same, which is why you can often use EF Core to load entities and return them directly. Quite often there are shape differences, which is why AutoMapper is often used to *flatten* or unflatten DTOs by name. In your case though, this is a completely different model

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The purpose is type safety. Also, questioning the "purpose" isn't very constructive. How to set the `BindingSource` through providers instead of annotations is a valid question, even outside of the simplified example given.

Comment: Type safety in your API comes from the OpenAPI/Swagger schema and the validation middleware that run before the model binder itself. The validations take into account the annotation attributes of the *API* DTOs, or validation-specific interfaces (IValidateObject). If you want type safety without attributes, you'll have to add IValidationObject in your no-longer-business entities. The implementation will have to handle the (necessarily) different validation rules used in DTOs and domain entities

Comment: [remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model #API360](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/)

Comment: The solution I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883548/custom-model-binder-for-a-webapi-method-with-more-than-one-parameter/56893947#56893947) (last code snippet) should help here, I think.

Comment: @KirkLarkin It works! It does require `BindingSource.Path` instead of `BindingSource.Special` of course. Would you like to write an answer so I can reward you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[ApiController]` attribute applies [binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/#binding-source-parameter-inference) to a controller:

> [FromBody] is inferred for complex type parameters not registered in the DI Container.

In your example, `Id<TEntity>` is a complex type, so it gets an *implied* `[FromBody]` attribute when used as a controller parameter.

To override this, and *imply* a `[FromRoute]` attribute, add a `BindingSourceMetadataProvider` for the type that uses [`BindingSource.Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.bindingsource.path#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-modelbinding-bindingsource-path):

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{                    
    // ...

    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(
        new BindingSourceMetadataProvider(typeof(Id<>), BindingSource.Path));
});
```

Comment: Generics don't appear to work. Instead I used reflection to find all entities and generate a provider for each unique `Id<TEntity>`.

Answer (score 0):

For change the default source IModelBinder in ASP.NET, can use the [ModelBinder] attribute on your Id type. By applying this you can specify the default binding source for your model. [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

If don't understand from this source, see below example:

```
[ModelBinder(BindingSource = BindingSource.Path)]
public record struct Id<TEntity>(int Value);
```

After applying this your controller action can be simplified as follows:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetById(Id<Product> id)
{
    // Your implementation here
}
```

ASP.NET will automatically bind the Id parameter from the route by default, as specified in the [ModelBinder] attribute.

Hope help you! :))

Comment: Quoting the last line in my question: "If this can be fixed by annotating Id<TEntity>, then this is not an option. It lives in a separate library that is unaware of ASP.NET". But it has given me a better search direction, because now I at least know which property controls the binding source.

Comment: If you can't directly annotate Id<TEntity> or modify the separate library, you can create a custom attribute and apply it to your action method parameters to set the default binding source.

Comment: @RickdeWater next you'll have to modify the validation middleware, or add `IValidateObject` to your business entities. What you do is wrong and will get uglier the more you try to push this.

Comment: Sorry, I helped you to the best of my ability and knowledge, I don't know more than that.