# Post multiple primitive parameters

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Prior to .net core, Rick Strahl had a great article on how to post and accept primitive parameters in web api. I was able to use his solution to accept multiple primitive parameters.

Things have changed a little for .net core, and he has offered a similar solution here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers

There is just one problem though, this solution only seems supports 1 parameter. In the previous solution he cached the data when reading the content so that subsequent requests did not need to read it again (since it could only be read once). The thing that's different this time, however, is that you must use the `[FromBody]` attribute and it won't fire the method on the custom InputFormatter to get the parameter if you don't use that attribute. However, .net raises an exception if you use this attribute more than once. It totally ignores the fact that you may have handled the issue of caching the content yourself and so it seems to absolutely force the issue of only allowing you to post a single parameter this way.

I have always been able to pass multiple single primitive values in other frameworks I've used, and I'm not interested in having to create a library of strongly typed classes for every combination of parameters I might use in all my service calls. Is there any way around this?

Before workarounds were found for web api (before core), there were people who decided not to use webapi just over this issue so I know I'm not alone on this. So to be clear, I know how I can modify my code to accomplish the task at hand using alternative solutions... but if it's possible I'd like to actually be able to use multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many parameters, but only one parameter per action may be bound from body, and that's because an HTTP message can only have one body. So, When there are multiple parameters in the body that need to be bound, you can combine them into one class that just wraps / holds these parameters as properties and use this object to bind parameters.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53854544/11965297), you can refer to it.

Comment: No, it's not b/c there is only one body. It's b/c Microsoft add validation to prevent using more than one FromBody attribute. There is absolutely no reason why a custom solution couldn't cache the parameters on the first read. And that's exactly what the solution I use for web api does b/c it doesn't require the FromBody attribute in order to work the way .net core does.